# Linear independence of columns and rows of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read somewhere in my Algebra 1 notes something about how if a matrix has $n$ linearly independent rows (or it might have been columns) then it's rank is $n$. If this is the correct statement can someone please explain this, I can't seem to understand why this is true. 
   However, if this statement has been quoted incorrectly, please can you correct it. Apologies if there is an error in my quotation, I can't find my notes.

I refer to rank as dim(Im(A)) i.e. the dimension of the A's image space.

Comment: Well, in order to understand better *what it is you don't understand", write down in your question what is it for you "rank of a matrix" .

Comment: The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the image space dim(Im(A)).

Comment: @Sam Fine. Now, do you know that $\;\text{Im}\,A\;$ is spanned by the matrix's *columns*? And do you know that the number of linearly independent columns in **any** matrix equals the number of lin. ind. *rows* of that matrix?

Comment: @DonAntonio How does one get to know that?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson Proving it. It is a rather standard result in basic linear algebra: the number of lin. ind. columns in any matrix equals the number of lin. ind. rows in that matrix, and thus row rank equals the column rank...and it is then possible to define the rank of a matrix without problems.

Comment: I don't know where to start in proving it. It makes intuitive sense that if I have linearly independent columns that I'll have linearly independent rows, because a square matrix seems like the obvious example. But I don't know that it would necessarily be true with a non-square matrix. What if you have a row of zeros at the bottom? (Pivot in every column but not every row)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The rank is the dimension of the column space (a.k.a. range or image) of a matrix. The column space is the span of the columns of the matrix. So one way to think of the rank is the size of a basis of the column space.

Some consequences:

- If the matrix has $n$ columns, and $k$ of the columns are linearly independent, then the rank is at least $k$, since the span of these $k$ columns (which has dimension $k$) is a subspace of the column space.
- If all $n$ columns of the matrix are linearly independent, then the columns themselves are a basis of the column space, so the rank is $n$.

Answer (score -1):

The image of the matrix will be the span of the images of the basis vectors, i.e. the columns of the matrix. If there are $n$ linearly independent columns then the rank will evidently be $n$.

To see why the first line holds take a vector **x**=$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \mathbf{e_i}$. First see that the image of a basis vector is the column of the matrix M since for the $k^{th}$ basis vector $(M\mathbf{e_k})_i =M_{ij}e_j=M_{ij}\delta_{jk}=M_{ik}$ which is the $i^{th}$ element of the $k^{th}$ column. Now we can apply $M$ to each component of **x** in the basis so $M\mathbf{x}$ would be in the span of the columns of M.

You can proceed similarly for the rows.

Comment: This answer seems to assume the OP, and the answerer, have a definition of "rank of a matrix" independent of "number of linearly independent rows", so please include that definition in your answer.

Comment: Did you mean something like this?

Comment: It looks better though a little messy still. Anyway I didn't downvote, which is something I don't usually do.